# What equation describes the face of a cube?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

Picture a huge cube shaped planet of edges of many thousand miles. Assume that the distribution of the material (say oak wood) within the cube is homogenous.

Now, imagine the oaklings doing geodesy. They do not have the slightest idea about the shape of their planet. They just walk around and try to mathematically describe the surface. This is how they picture their world before they would discover that they actually live on the surface of a huge cube:

[image]

The red sketch is an artistic reproduction of the planet, as one of the oaklings pictured before the great discoveries.

(I have been trying to write up the equation with no success. As far as I can imagine the oaklings measured the angle between the axis of their body and the floor. From this angle (changing everywhere) I couldn'n make up the equation.)

**EDIT**

What do I mean by an equation? Let's say, the length of an edge is $2d$. Let the origin of our coordinate system be located at the center of a face of the cube. An equation would look like this one below:

$$\operatorname{height}(x,y)=\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2&\text{ if } (x,y)\in [-d,d]\times[-d,d]\\
\text{undefined}&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Unfortunately this is not the right equation.

Comment: That surface does not look like one of the six surfaces of a cube... Is the planet only approximately a cube? And if it *is* a perfect cube, then it would simply be a ... very large cube. Either way, I don't see what you are trying to do.

Comment: The problem described is not so clear,  With respect to origin cube surfaces may be $ (x-a)(x+a)(y-a)(y+a)(z-a)(z+a)=0 $

Comment: @Lovsovs: You might be right... No. For somebody walking on a massive sphere the surface would look like a sphere... No. It would look like a plane.

Comment: I agree it would look like a plane, but that seems trivial, hence my questioning whether I understood your question.

Comment: @Lovsovs: So the massive sphere looks to be a plane. What does a massive cube  look like for those walking on its surface. My excellent drawing tries to display what the walkers see. I just don't know the equation.

Comment: ... It would still look like a plane, which would be slightly slanted.

Comment: @Lovsovs: No. You will feel like walking up hill then you would encounter an edge. Then you would walk downwards. When at the corner of the cube you would feel like being at the top of a mountain.

Comment: Ugh, that is what "slanted" means.

Comment: @Losovs: Just to make sure I understand English: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6ruW.png

Comment: It's unclear what "equation" you are looking for. Please clarify the mathematical content of your question. (Aside: calling your own graphics "excellent" is a sure way of putting peoples' backs up.)

Comment: @RobArthan: I edited my question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is still very unclear.

Comment: @RobArthan: Then vote for closing. But before you would do that I make a last attempt to explain the point. Can you imagine yourself walking on such a surface? You would feel that you walk upwards when approaching the edges. You would feel that the height is increasing. I was hoping that somebody would help describing the equation of the height felt.

Comment: The "height" would be the distance from your location on the cube-shaped planet to the centre of the planet.

Comment: The oaklings, once they think about it a bit, will figure out that height is not actually increasing. They have a clear line of sight from one end of the face to the other, and they can measure the curvature of the ground at any point and find it to be zero; both observations will tell them that they are living on the flat face of a polyhedron. Instead, what they will realize is that gravity is pointing in different directions as they move along the surface, and may be able to infer the location of the center of the cube from that.

Comment: @Rahul: Like the earthlings found out that the curvature of their surface is $\frac1{R^2}$. No, the Earthlings believed for thousands of years that the surface is flat. **But you enlightened me**: My question should not have been asked in such a funny way. So, I will delete my question in a few minutes. I'll wait a little to make sure that you read my comment.

Comment: Are you waiting for me to acknowledge that I have read your comment?

Comment: On a cube, _three_ square faces meet at a corner, while the diagram shows _four_. The "defect" of one face is a substantial piece of information about intrinsic curvature. :)

Comment: @Rahul: Sorry: I've changed my mind when somebody upvoted the down vote. Then I decided to fundamentally edit my question. Please, take a look at it now.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: Yeah. That's the artist's error not mine : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure that you’ve provided enough information to come up with a definitive equation, but here’s one possibility. It looks like you’ve got square tiles with “altitude” given by the distance from the cube’s center.

For a single tile, consider a cube with side length $2s$ centered at the origin and aligned with the coordinate planes. Using spherical coordinates, the “altitude” that the oaklings would measure along the top face of this cube is simply $s\sec\theta$. We also have $\tan\theta=R/s$, where $R$ is the distance from the center of the face, so relative to the center of a tile the altitude is given by $$s\sqrt{1+(R/s)^2}=\sqrt{s^2+R^2}=\sqrt{s^2+(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2}$$ where $(x_c,y_c)$ are the coordinates of the tile center in the “flattened” version of the world.

Comment: The oaklings does not measure the distance from the center of the cube. They don't even know that they are walking on a cube. As I clearly said: "As far as I can imagine the oaklings measured the angle between the axis of their body and the floor. "

Comment: That will give you something similar, if not identical, since that angle is $\pi-\theta$.